# Symbolic Logic Proof -- Typo?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I was working through some proofs in my symbolic logic book when I came across the following problem:

$$\text{Given:}$$
$$\\ (A \lor B) \implies(C \lor D)$$
$$\\ (C \implies W) \land (D \implies \neg A)$$
$$\\A \land \neg W$$
$$\text{Prove:}$$
$$\neg(C \lor D)$$

My Proof:

By Simplification 
$$A$$

By Addition
$$A \lor B$$

By Modus Ponens
$$C \lor D$$

This, however, is the negation of the expression I was asked to prove and (if my reasoning is correct) $\neg(C \lor D)$ cannot be inferred from the premises. Was there a mistake in the book or in my reasoning? Thanks.

Comment: When asked to prove something with three premises, and you prove the contrary using only two premises... then check to see if using the third premise leads to a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. That's a good tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I suspect there's a typo there - **those hypotheses are inconsistent**.

Although that said, technically the problem does work as stated - *an inconsistent theory proves everything*. So it is possible that this was intensional.

---

Here's how the inconsistency comes about roughly:

- Since by $(3)$ we know $A$ is true, $A\vee B$ is true and so $(1$) tells us that either $C$ or $D$ is true.
- $(2)$ tells us that if $C$ were true, then $W$ would be true; since $(3)$ tells us that $W$ is false, we know that $C$ is false.
- ... And so $D$ must be true. But then $(2)$ tells us that $\neg A$ is true, and this contradicts $(3)$.

Now as noted above, since an inconsistent system proves everything this is *technically* a valid exercise; but I don't really think this was what was intended.

Comment: It's not a typo.  It is *because* the premises are inconsistent that you can validly prove inconsistent conclusions.

Comment: @GrahamKemp Your second sentence, which is what my answer points out, doesn't imply your first: it's fully possible (and my suspicion) that the authors intended to write something else but messed up - but luckily resulted in a still-correct problem. Of course I could be wrong and this could be intentional, but my knee-jerk reaction is that something else was meant.

Answer (score 2):

Your proof that $C\lor D$ follows is correct. However, $\lnot(C\lor D)$ also follows, so the premises are inconsistent.

We can prove it by contradiction. (I will be very informal so as to allow you to construct the formal proof.)

If $C$ holds, then since we have $C\to W,$ $W$ holds, but we also have $\lnot W.$ If $D$ holds, then since we have $D\to \lnot A,$ $\lnot A$ holds. But we also have $A.$